# In Excel 2010, how do you show the last time a row of cells was updated?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a project table that my whole team has access to. Each row is a specific project and they update the appropriate cells in the for those projects. The problem has become that the Last Updated column reflecting the dates each row was last updated has not been kept up.

Is there a way to automatically put the date in a cell at the end of a row that has been updated?

Comment: **In which column should the date be entered ??**

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way.

You would use an *Event Macro* that would monitor any changes to the project data and automatically enter the date in the appropriate column.